# Can I use xmpp for other purposes?

Tags: android, xmpp

I need to build a real-time android application. I just wondering, can I use xmpp for my data transmission solution? I've been looking around, and most of xmpp clients are used for chatting.

Comment: http://fyi.oreilly.com/2009/05/what-can-you-do-with-xmpp.html (thats a yes, xmpp is not used only for chatting, but much more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, XMPP messages are based on XML, so if you have a small amount of structured data you want to send, you should be fine. Large data is a problem, however. From the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) page:

> Because XMPP is not yet encoded as Efficient XML Interchange but as a single long XML
>   document, binary data must be first base64 encoded before it can be transmitted in-band. 
>   Therefore any significant amount of binary data (e.g., file transfers) is best transmitted 
>   out-of-band, using in-band messages to coordinate. The best example of this is the Jingle 
>   XMPP Extension Protocol, XEP-0166.